# In responsive design my images are cut off and table paragraphs cut off on the right side

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, media-queries, html-table

After reading many articles, I can't seem to find an answer as to why my images have no margin on the right side and my table paragraph text gets cut off on the right side. The paragraph text is fine on my other pages, just in the table it gets cut off. 
This is all using css3 media queries responsive design. This happened to another site I built for a client. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Here is my css media query for the phone screen:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url("phone.css") only screen and (max-width:320px);
container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
 }
#header img {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#navigation {
    font-size:large;
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    overflow:hidden;


}
#menu {
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.nav-btn {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#09F;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:15px 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:large;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
.nav-btn:after {
    content:url(images/mobilemenu.png);

}
#menu li {
        width:100%;
        font-size:large;
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:#09F;
        display:block;
        margin:0px;
        border:#000 medium solid;
        float:none;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-align:center;
}

#menu img {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    position:relative;

}

#navigation ul li {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:none;
    overflow:hidden;

}

#menu li a {
    width:100%;
    display:block;

}

#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}


.socialmedia {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    max-width:30px;
    max-height:30px;

}




.bigfoot {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
}




#content img {

    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:5px;
}

#content table, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display:block;



}
#content table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative; 
    min-width:320px;
}

#content td p {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;



}


#content tr {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#content td {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}


#content tr td img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-height:250px;
    max-width:250px;

}



#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

And my html for the page:

```
<div style="background-image:url(images/beer%20content%20background2.jpg)" id="content"> 

  <h1 align="center">Our Beers</h1>
  <p>

  <table class="beers" align="center" width="550" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="images/Alberts_Web.png" alt="albert's ale" width="350"/>
    <p>Albert's Ale is a German inspired beer with a crisp malt base, and 2 varieties of hops. This pale ale is hoppy, and a real refreshing thirst quencher. Enjoy year round! <br />6% Alcohol.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <img src="images/Hieroglyph_Web.png" alt="Hieroglyph"width="350"/>
    <p> Hieroglyph is a double IPA. 8% Alcohol.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="images/Trapezeious_Web.png" alt="Trapezious" width="350"/>

    </td>
    <td>
    <img src="images/Sifu_Web.png" alt="Sifu" width="350"/>

    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
<h2 align="center">Occasional & Seasonal brews</h2>
  <table class="beers" align="center" width="550" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="images/Krock'd_Web.png" alt="Krock'd" width="350"/>

    </td>
    <td>
    <img src="images/Viking_Web.png" alt="I Wish I was a Viking" width="350"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="images/Fat Bobby_Web.png" alt="Fat Bobby" width="350"/>

    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>



  </p>

  <br />
  <p align="center">Check out our upcoming events where we will be sampling our beer!</p>
  <p align="center">Cheers!</p>
</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

</div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

A quick note, I did apply the viewport meta tag on all of my pages to initial scale 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: There are no media queries in the code you posted...

Apart from that: Although *in the CSS* you define the width for your tables as 100%, you have inline settings that give the tables 550px width:

```
<table class="beers" align="center" width="550" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
```

I suppose that's the reason for them not fitting on a mobile screen. Erase all that inline stuff that interferes with the CSS.

Similarly with images...

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, I did get rid of the inline style on the table width. My paragraph words are still getting cut off on the right side.

Comment: well, also your inline image widths add up to 700px, so that can't work on a small screen (erase those, too)